# Mongoid concatenation search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

until today I was making simple name search on my user collection with this query

```
User.where({ '$or'=> [ { firstName: regExp }, { lastName: regExp } ] })
```

which works fine, but if I want to do my search queries on the full string `firstname lastname` , should I create  an other "fullname"  field and or is there a better alternative ?

Comment: Can you post an example regexp that you are using?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the **aggregation framework** to perform a projection with the use of the `$concat` operator and then match the projected field with your regexp.

Anyway a benchmark test against your query would be really useful to know how fast it performs.

```
User.collection.aggregate(
    {
        :$project => {
            :fullname => {:$concat => ["$firstName", " ", "$lastName"]}
        }
    },
    {
        :$match => {
            :fullname => regExp
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: Does Mongoid support $concat already? I use the newest stable version (3.1.6) and it says, "invalid operator, $concat"

Comment: AFAIK all the Aggregation Framework is supported at driver level by Moped since version 1.3.0

Comment: Later I figured it out that it was due to my mongoDB that is 2.2.. $concat is available from 2.4...So, no problem with mongoid/moped ...Thanks for your information :)